# Use Theorem 1.1.1 below to verify the logical equivalence and supply a reason for each step?

Tags: logic

[Logical Equivalences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNHJJ.png)

I have question about  Simplifying Statement Forms, this question

$$\lnot(p \lor \lnot q) \lor(\lnot p \land \lnot q) ≡ \lnot p$$

and this my answer 
$$\begin{align}
    \lnot(p \lor \lnot q) \lor(\lnot p \land \lnot q) &≡ (\lnot p \land \lnot\lnot q) \lor (\lnot p \land \lnot q)&&\text{De Morgan’s laws}\\
              &≡(\lnot p \land q) \lor (\lnot p \land \lnot q)&&\text{Double Negative law}\\
              &≡p \land (q \lor \lnot q)   &&\text{Distributive laws}\\
              &≡p \land t    &&\text{Negation laws}\\
              &≡p         &&\text{Identity laws}\\
\end{align}$$

my answer is correct or not ?

Comment: There is just a typo when you apply the distributive law: you get $\lnot p \land (q \lor \lnot q)$. You keep $\lnot p$ in the next lines.

Comment: oke thank you're explanation :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to MSE! 
No, its not correct. The third line should be $\neg p \wedge (q\vee \neg q)$.

Comment: just three line? , oke thank you for you correction